# c++ - variable that can hold istreams?

Tags: c++, dynamic, stream, char

I am making a dynamic `char` string class, and I have a function that that will get input until a delimiter, and put it into the dynamic string.

what I was wondering is if there is a way to save the stream into a variable, that can hold either a `cin`, or `ifstream`.

I am currently using function overloading, but it is annoying having to edit each function each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a standard-conformant compiler, `cin` is an instance of some subclass of `istream`, and the `ifstream` class inherits from `istream`.

This means you can use an `istream` (reference, pointer...) as function parameter for everything.

Comment: This helps so much thank you! I was hoping inheritance would play a roll, but didn't know how.

Answer (score 1):

> I currently am using function over loading, but it is annoying having to edit each function each time.

You can easily reduce your function overloads by receiving `std::istream` references:

```
 class MyType {
 public:
      void get(std::istream& is) {
          is >> x >> y;
      }
 private:
      int x;
      int y;
 };

 std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, MyType& myType) {
     myType.get(is);
     return is;
 }
```

`std::ifstream` inherits from `std::istream` as well as `std::cin`s type does. So you can fall back to the `std::istream` reference.